# Background image flashes when changed via state

Tags: reactjs

An example of what I am talking about is here: https://detrum-replication.herokuapp.com/

My problem can be seen when the hovering diamond in the bottom left is clicked.  I have both the gradient and background rendered conditionally according to a value in the state.  It just cycles from 1-4 and changes the class of the divs according to the number of the state.  The only thing that I don't like is the split second flash when the diamond is clicked.  Once the images have been loaded and cycled through it no longer flashes so I assume the images have been cached.  Is there a way to precache the images I will be using for the background using React?  Did I go about this in the wrong way to achieve what I am trying to do?  I have tried using a few precachers for React with no luck.  Some of my code is as follows:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        bg: 1
    }
}

changeSeason = () => {
        let current = this.state.bg;

        if (current >= 4){
            current = 1;
        } else {
            current++;
        }

        this.setState(() => ({bg : current}));
        localStorage.setItem("bg", current);
};
render() {
    return (
        <div className={`gradient${this.state.bg}`}>
            <div className={`background${this.state.bg}`}></div>
            <div className="diamond" onClick={this.changeSeason}><div className="diamond__shadow-bottom"></div><div className="diamond__shadow-right"></div></div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **preload** assets on your app when you know for sure you would be needing them. The browser doesn't wait for your javascript/css to parse and know that you need them, thereby preventing the flicker.

You need to add them to your **index.html** like this

```
<link rel="preload" href="bg-image.png" as="image">
```

Look at the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content) docs for reference

Comment: what if the image from API call ?

Comment: Then you would have to wait to make the API call and it's response, isn't it? You can't make use of preload in such scenarios.

Preloading is for static assets you bundle with code like fonts, and images like banner, logo, icons etc. You should only use it when you definitely need it on every initial load